# Вопрос по RectTransform UI объектов (ширина, высота, позиция по оси x и y)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть, допустим, кнопка `button`, у которой позиция в родительском объекте такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. кнопка имеет ширину и высоту, а привязана она только к центру верхней границы родительского элемента, и по оси `y` имеет отступ 100 пикселей.

Когда я вывожу эти значения в лог следующим образом:

```
RectTransform rect = button.GetComponent<RectTransform>();            
        Debug.Log(rect.rect.height);
        Debug.Log(rect.rect.width);
        Debug.Log(rect.rect.x);
        Debug.Log(rect.rect.y);
```

то получаю такой вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, что обозначают последние два вывода в лог? Почему по оси `x` я получаю не 0, а -125, а по оси `y` не -100, а -50?

Comment: скорее всего это глобальные значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё достаточно просто - в лог Вы выводите параметры структуры Rect. Вам же необходимы `anchoredPosition` и `sizeDelta`.

В Инспекторе включите Debug-режим отображения ("иконка меню" -> Nornal/Debug) и Вам всё станет ясно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за подсказку насчет Debug-режим, но все же я хочу понять, что обозначают эти цифры, которые вывелись в лог последними двумя строками. Вот что у меня выдает Debug-режим: cloud.mail.ru/public/DEfN%2FDf4VaMq8X

Comment: @Volha [RectTransform-rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html) и [Rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html)

Comment: ну если вы поняли, так объясните, в этом же и заключался (частично) вопрос!

Comment: Это глобальные координаты "начала координат" структуры (т.е. верхний левый угол RectTransform). И в документации говорится об этом.

Comment: дело в том, что в документации говорится обо всем, там есть ответы на абсолютно все вопросы. Но этот форум, насколько я понимаю, создан ни для того, чтобы отсылать к документации при первом удобном случае. Иначе бы этот форум можно было бы просто закрыть, а на главной странице написать примерно следующее: "Есть вопросы по юнити? Читайте документацию!" Надеюсь на понимание

Comment: Просто мне показалось, что это понятно по ссылке выше, особенно по [изображению](https://docs.unity3d.com/StaticFiles/ScriptRefImages/RectXY.svg) из мануала. Прошу прощения, просто порой некоторые вещи кажутся настолько интуитивно понятными, что упомянув их вскользь, забываешь заострить внимание на подробностях.

Comment: в общем, путем экспериментов, я выяснила, что `rect.x` и `rect.y` - это расположение в пикселях точки пивота UI объекта относительно его же левого нижнего угла. Т.е. если у объекта пивот задан 0,0 (т.е. пивот находится в левом нижнем углу), тогда `rect.x` и  `rect.y` будут равны нулю, если пивот сместить, к примеру, в центр, то `rect.x` вернет значение (- "ширина объекта/2)", а `rect.y` вернет (- "высота объекта/2"). Причем у дочерних элементов, вложенных в этот, такая же история, т.е. это всегда точка пивота текущего объекта. Короче, сама себе ответила на вопрос )))

Comment: Однозначно плюс за Ваши изыскания.